# How to hide query string parameters in hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
<a href="javascript:OpenPopUp('/demo/control?check=guide&rfc= <%= (String) session.getAttribute(DemoConstants.RFC_Ticket) %>');" Demo</a><BR>
```

If I click on Demo URL all the values in the hyperlink are populating in the browser address bar.

Is there any way to hide the Query String parameters in the above hyperlink.

Note: All the other values in this form are submitting via POST method.

Thanks in advance, **Naga**

Comment: Encode them ? you can't hide them if it is a GET.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hide variables passed in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650408/hide-variables-passed-in-url)

Comment: if your using form submit means simple pass it as a hidden input field

Comment: @JYoThI Clearly not.

Comment: @SureshAtta.. Query parameter values are already encoded, but still need to hide them in the address bar. All the other values in the form are passing via post method. I'm not sure how to pass these hyper link query parameter values using post. Please suggest.

Comment: @NagaRameshBusam Nope. You cannot with GET.

Comment: @SureshAtta.. Is there any way to make the above URL as using POST?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the History API.
So first process the parameters when you land on the given page and then "remove" them, e.g `history.replaceState({}, null, location.pathname);`

Comment: Can get it from browser history ??

Comment: @SureshAtta `history.replaceState()` [modifies the current history entry instead of creating a new one.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method)